# Calculating a value in an entity based on other entities?

Tags: doctrine-orm

usually it's pretty simple to return a calculated value from an entity.
Given e.g.

```
/**
* @ORM\Column()
*/
private $baseValue;

(...)

public function getCalculatedValue() {
    return $this->baseValue * 1.19;
}
```

In my case the calculation is depending on the existing of other entities of the same type.

In my case the calculated Value is (in PseudoCode):

```
(100 / totalCountOfEntitiesOfTheSameType -1) * thisEntity.value
```

or as repository method:

```
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('COUNT(e.id)');
    $qb->from($this->getClassName(), 'e');

    $totalCount = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

    if ($totalCount > 1) {
        return (100 / ($totalCount - 1)) * $step->getStepOrder();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```

I want to avoid calling the repository in a service (e.g. my API is no service but just virtual JMS properties of my entity's properties).

Is there any way to expose this function with my entity itself?

Or is there a way to precalculate this value for every entity and persist it (which would force me to update all existing entities of this kind)?

Comment: Why would you want to calculate values inside the entities anyways? Such code does not belong there, Doctrine Entities are containing objects only. They hold data, may have some default values, but no business logic.

Comment: How are you loading the entity without using the entity manager or repository?  I don't understand the "avoid calling the repository" portion of your question.

Comment: @StoryTeller I totally agree with you. Doctrine Objects should only be DAOs and for any other stuff I'd usually have some DTOs or something similar. But I want to avoid a new layer just for "some, typically very easy" additional properties. I have to admit - and tried to explain - that this special case is not "very easy" but still - I was wondering if I got some chance.

Comment: @Cerad: I am loading it implicitly by another entity. So when I call $em->find(1) I get an object with a referring object loaded. But calling $object->getReferredObject()->getMyCalculatedValue() has to fail of course, neither direct EntityManager nor Repository call for ReferredObject then :-(

Comment: If within a given request/response you know you will need the counts for the related object then replace $em->find with a call to the parent object's repository.  Add the logic for grabbing the count of the related object into there.  That way, your resulting object graph will have all the data your app need for the request.